# Simultaneous two OkHttp websocket connections, one of them getting thread starved

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp, java-threads

In my spring boot app that I'm running in Intellij I have one @Scheduled task, and two WebSocket streams open to two different servers using OkHttp connections from two different instances of OkHttpClients. I don't think the Connection pool setting in the OkHttpClient.Builder is of relevance here since there are two instances of OkHttpClient. Both the websocket streams receive some events initially and then one of them never receives any event anymore. I have also verified by printing the hashcode of the worker threads that they are different. [![image][1]][1]

Sadly I notice the same problem on the command line mvn run also, so it doesn't seem to be an Intellij specific issue.

How can I make the events received on both socket streams continously? Will it help if I reused the same OkHttpClient to create both the connections?

Update: Not wanting to waste time waiting to solve this I went to the extreme step of separating into 2 separate applications each with a websocket listener. Yet I face the same issue, one of them stops receiving any callback after a few seconds of starting. Can't blame it on the remote server, because if I ran any one of them individually, it never stops receiving the callback stream. I need them to be up and running simultaneously and communicate with one another.

fwiw, I'm using [this][2] client library to subscribe to one WebSocket stream, and [this][3] for another. The first endpoint is wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@aggTrade and the second is wss://fstream.binance.com. The latter subscription is established by posting a JSON {"method":"SUBSCRIBE","id":1663348051361,"params":"btcusdt@aggTrade"} to it.

I have chatted with the customer support of the server endpoints, they are unable to help me, they just said that if I'm able to subscribe to the socket stream individually just fine, they don't see any reason why one of them should stop working when I bring them up both at the same time.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5oia.png
[2]: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/binance/api/client/impl/BinanceApiWebSocketClientImpl.java#L47
[3]: https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/binance/client/impl/WebSocketStreamClientImpl.java#L63

Answer (score 1):

Each WebSocket gets its own thread. Could it be something in your listener?

Comment: If there is, there is nothing on the console to indicate listener crash, like an uncaught exeption.

Comment: You are right, when I put logging statement for Enter and Exit the listener method, I notice that a few seconds after running properly, there is an Enter without an Exit, so something is indeed wrong in my listener code, or this thread gets preempted and for some reason only the other listener thread prevails from there on.

Comment: A correction, there is no bug in my listener. There was another return statement in the middle where I forgot to print my Exit logging, now there is no imbalance seen between Enter and Exit. It just stops getting called suddenly.

Comment: Two main possibilities, jvm cpu core assignments, and another thread priority , is each run  in a thread so the priority can be assigned. A last thought would be http protocol connection "state" stateless or state explicit (or a combination of any all). Another, limit connections to the host by calling domain.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have `stream.binance.com:9443` and `fstream.binance.com` listed as 2 host:port then may be served by a single server.

And even if you separated these 2 clients into its own jvm (to rule out threading and other issues) your clientIp and other parameters might make the 2 clients looks like 1.

I suggest try to make these 2 client subscriptions look different by spoofing client ip header. Perhaps set X-Forwarded-For and/or the X-Real-IP.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67103219/2103767 might help in providing that socket

**Update:**

Are you sending pong frame ?

According to https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#websocket-market-streams you must send a pong frame otherwise it will disconnect the client.

*The websocket server will send a ping frame every 5 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 15 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed.*

Not sure if it suits your needs but you can listen to 2 channels with same client.

Comment: This doesn't sound correct.  Are you talking about congestion on the local network, or at the other end, with a single server possibly handling both requests?

Comment: Nothing to do with congestion but rather identifying the client as 1. Sure it could be same server but I meant same system that tracks client session by IP address (besides same API keys and credentials.). I suggest you print the request/response information for any codes they might be sending